# Correct usage of data/body with axios in node.js

Tags: node.js, axios

I get the error 'NOT_FOUND' with the error code of 404 when trying this code:

```
    axios.get(`https://api.exchange.bitpanda.com/public/v1/account/deposit/crypto`, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer api_key'
      },
      data: {
        "currency": "BTC"
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
    })
```

For some reason there are no examples in node.js

[Picture of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg5fJ.png)

[Bitpanda api documentation](https://developers.bitpanda.com/exchange/?shell#deposit-crypto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 404 because request to `https://api.exchange.bitpanda.com/public/v1/account/deposit/crypto` should be `POST` not `GET` as per the [documentation](https://developers.bitpanda.com/exchange/?shell#deposit-crypto)

```
 axios.post(REST_OF_THE_CODE_HERE);
```

Also strutcture your request differently, read on how axios works [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)

```
const headers = 
 {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer api_key'
 }

axios.post(URL, payload, { headers: headers})
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
      })
     .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        console.log(error.response.status);
     })
```

Comment: Glad, consider upvoting ;)